# Permissions - How do I request and/or change them in phones running MIUI during runtime?

Tags: android, permissions

Apparently the MIUI OS has already implemented its own Permissions system before Marshmallow does. I'm currently testing a video recording app for the Xiaomi Mi 4i, which uses a MIUI based on API 21 [Android 5.0.2], and it needs the Record Audio permission which is not granted by default by MIUI's Permissions Manager.

So far the way I've managed to alter the permissions is by accessing the Permissions Manager window for the app on clicking the OK button in the AlertDialog:

```
isMIUI = MIUIUtils.isMIUI();
if(isMIUI)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setMessage("If you intend to use the video recording feature, please enable the 'Record Audio' permission in the settings menu. You will be redirected there if you press OK.")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
                intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
                intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", "com.picmix.mobile");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
        .create();
    adb.show();
}
```

But this isn't good enough for me. I need to check if the `Record Audio` permission is already checked in the MIUI Permissions Manager in order to run this only once.

How do I check for the permissions granted or to be notified in the MIUI Permissions Manager programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

```
private boolean resourceCanBeAccessed() {

        boolean response = true;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
                response = false;
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

You just need to call this method before accessing the resource. This method will return true if the permission is granted. It the permission is not granted then it will grant the permission

Comment: That only works in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow). The Xiaomi Mi 4i was identified with Android 5.0.2 (Lollipop), and this code will just return true for everything defined in the Manifest [the `Record Audio` permission is there, by the way]. The MIUI Permissions Manager makes things more complicated than just this.